# Rows in seperate sheets in workbook seem to be linked?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a problem where a colleague is editting a spreadsheet I provided in 2003 workbook format. When he is editing in Excel 2007, he is inserting a row on one sheet in the workbook. This is fine but the same new row gets inserted into all the other sheets. He has saved teh sheet in 2007 format before this problem occurred. I don't have the issue when I open it (and it gets converted into 2003) but I don't have 2007 to test it. Ive got someone else to try with 2007 an dthey can't re-produce it either.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

1. Watch what your colleague does to make this happen.  I guarantee it's not 'just magick'
2. Make sure macros are disabled.  This is so specific, I wonder if a macro is getting run without their knowledge.

If afyter trying these you still can't figure out what's going on, you might try posting the file - perhaps someone can diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though ungrouping the sheets might help (try clicking on one of the sheet name tabs that is not emboldened).